# What is BW stands for in Skia maskformat?

Tags: skia, skiasharp

I tried search everywhere, but can't find what is BW stands for. Here is the link: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/SkiaSharp.SKMaskFormat/
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs:

> 1-bit per pixel mask (e.g. monochrome).

This type of mask is a series of bit-states (mask/don't mask).

Comment: thanks a lot, so BW means Bitwise, do I understand correct?

Comment: To be really honest, I am not sure. Bitwise, maybe. I just thought it meant black/white. But, I don't think the name matters as long as you know that it bit-based. The more I think about it, it could be bitwise... Maybe ask on the skia forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/skia-discuss